# Rails, Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf

I get

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>   (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

when I try to use remote: true in a page with around 50 forms(If that matters, I don't get that problem anywhere else.)

There are many questions regarding the CSRF token. However, all solutions seem to stop my form from being remote. In other words, if I add

```
config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
```

to my application.rb or

```
authenticity_token: true
```

or

```
= f.hidden_field :authenticity_token, value: form_authenticity_token
```

to my form, the object is created but rails tries to respond with html instead of with js.
I also have the

> = csrf_meta_tags

Any idea on how to fix that? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: The problem is that I submit the forms using js with form.submit().

Comment: Do you have `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in your application_controller?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have other remote forms, only these 50 in one page give me an error. If that helps I will post how a form look like
= simple_form_for [current_user.school, current_user.hr_group, lesson], remote: true, method: :post do |f|

Comment: Use `hidden_field_tag` instead of `f.hidden_field`